# sql pivot month result to year format

Tags: postgresql

How can I get the year column information,
which is not clear like the month, in the header?

```
select 
isnull (group_info, 'grand total') as 'group_definition',
isnull (sum (case datepart(month, shipment_date) when 1 then amount end),0) as 1,
isnull (sum (case datepart(month, shipment_date) when 2 then amount end),0) as 2,
isnull (sum (case datepart(month, shipment_date) when 3 then amount end),0) as 3,
isnull (sum (case datepart(month, shipment_date) when 4 then amount end),0) as 4,
isnull (sum (case datepart(month, shipment_date) when 5 then amount end),0) as 5,
isnull (sum (case datepart(month, shipment_date) when 6 then amount end),0) as 6,
isnull (sum (case datepart(month, shipment_date) when 7 then amount end),0) as 7,
isnull (sum (case datepart(month, shipment_date) when 8 then amount end),0) as 8,
isnull (sum (case datepart(month, shipment_date) when 9 then amount end),0) as 9,
isnull (sum (case datepart(month, shipment_date) when 10 then amount end),0) as 10,
isnull (sum (case datepart(month, shipment_date) when 11 then amount end),0) as 11,
isnull (sum (case datepart(month, shipment_date) when 12 then amount end),0) as 12,
isnull (sum (amount),0) as grandtotal
from invoice
group by groupıng sets
((datepart(year, shipment_date), group_info), ());
```

Comment: Please share full table before giving the query

Comment: What I want to do is to add year information instead of month information in the upper columns. Example: How can I make the top line write 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022 instead of January, February, March...?